# Progress bar doesn't refresh when it reaches 100

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress

I have a circle progress bar that works, but when it reaches 100% it is supposed to refresh and start over, but it doesn't. Here is my JSFiddle(for some reason it does not work there, but it works on my browser)

https://jsfiddle.net/BrsJsk/5e9hs69y/5/

```
    window.onload = function() {
  var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
    quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
    quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
    quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
    quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
    counter = document.querySelector('.counter');


  var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 1000); // call function every second

  function incrementProg() {
    progress = progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'); //get current value
    progress++; // increment the progress bar value by 1 with every iteration
    progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
    counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
    setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
    if (progress == 100) {
      clearInterval(progInc); // clear timer when countdown is complete

    }
  }

  function setPie(progress) {
    /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
    if (progress <= 25) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');

    }

    /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
    }

    /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
    else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
    }

    /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
    else if (progress > 75 && progress < 100) {
      quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
      quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
      quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
      quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
      progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
    }
  }
}
.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
  /* invisible at -90deg */
}

.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  /* invisible at 90deg */
}


/* Just for demo */

div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}

<div data-progress="0">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
  <div class='counter'>100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: all you do at 100% is `if (progress == 100) {
      clearInterval(progInc);` stop the interval ... nothing to suggest you start over in your code

Comment: Remove the `window.onload =` part to make it work on JSFiddle. JSFiddle handles that part for you :-)

Comment: @JaromandaX How could I start it over?

Comment: *"when it reaches 100% it is supposed to refresh and start over"* - Why? Doesn't reaching 100% mean the task is completed?

Comment: @BrS - whatever way is appropriate - not clear from "do nothing" code like that as to what would be appropriate - replace `clearInterval(progInc)` with `progress = 0;`

Comment: @nnnnnn it is supposed to represent a minute. 60s passes and it starts all over again.

Comment: `it is supposed to represent a minute. 60s passes` - it takes 100 seconds to do 100% incrementing by 1% each second ... but, you knew that, right

Comment: there's more you need to fix though - https://jsfiddle.net/5e9hs69y/9/

Comment: something like - https://jsfiddle.net/5e9hs69y/10/ (note, 10 x speed, who wants to wait for a minute to see if it works, right :p ) note: resets after a count of 60, and the setPie converts incoming value as a percentage of 60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only stop the interval when reaching 100% progress. To start over, you have to actively reset the progress. You can do so as follows.

Instead of reading the progress and incrementing it, do this.

```
progress = parseInt(progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'));
progress = ((progress + 1) % 100);
```

That is, [treat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the progress as an integer (because that's what it is) and then wrap the progress around to 0 when reaching 100 using the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder).

You also have to reset all quadrants of your progress bar.

```
if (progress === 0) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
    quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
}
```

This you can insert right after updating the progress. You can get rid of the lines that clear the interval.

**Full demo.** I made the interval slightly faster, just for demo purposes.

```js
var progressbar = document.querySelector('div[data-progress]'),
  quad1 = document.querySelector('.quad1'),
  quad2 = document.querySelector('.quad2'),
  quad3 = document.querySelector('.quad3'),
  quad4 = document.querySelector('.quad4'),
  counter = document.querySelector('.counter');


var progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 50);

function incrementProg() {
  progress = parseInt(progressbar.getAttribute('data-progress'));
  progress = ((progress + 1) % 100);
  if (progress === 0) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
    quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
  }
  progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', progress); //set value to attribute
  counter.textContent = 100 - parseInt(progress, 10); // set countdown timer's value
  setPie(progress); // call the paint progress bar function based on progress value
}

function setPie(progress) {
  /* If progress is less than 25, modify skew angle the first quadrant */
  if (progress <= 25) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + progress * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');

  }

  /* Between 25-50, hide 1st quadrant + modify skew angle of 2nd quadrant */
  else if (progress > 25 && progress <= 50) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 25) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  }

  /* Between 50-75, hide first 2 quadrants + modify skew angle of 3rd quadrant */
  else if (progress > 50 && progress <= 75) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(' + (progress - 50) * (-90 / 25) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  }

  /* Similar to above for value between 75-100 */
  else if (progress > 75 && progress < 100) {
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 1st completely
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(90deg)'); // hides 2nd completely
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(-90deg)'); // hides 3rd completely
    quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(' + (progress - 75) * (90 / 25) + 'deg)');
    progressbar.setAttribute('style', 'box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 50px #6edbf2');
  }
}
```

```css
div[data-progress] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #c8c9cb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.counter {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
}

div>div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.quad1,
.quad2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.quad3,
.quad4 {
  left: 0%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.quad1,
.quad4 {
  top: 0%;
}

.quad2,
.quad3 {
  top: 50%;
}

.quad1,
.quad3 {
  transform: skew(0deg);
  /* invisible at -90deg */
}

.quad2,
.quad4 {
  transform: skewY(0deg);
  /* invisible at 90deg */
}


/* Just for demo */

div[data-progress] {
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<div data-progress="0">
  <div class="quad1"></div>
  <div class="quad2"></div>
  <div class="quad3"></div>
  <div class="quad4"></div>
  <div class='counter'>100</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! 
Another question, in order for the progress bar to around exactly 60s and then reset itself, all I need to do is change to interval of speed?

Comment: Yes, although be aware that if you ask for a certain interval, it will not be guaranteed that you will get exactly that speed. Thus, your "clock" will eventually run out of sync with the actual time. That said, just set the interval to 60 seconds / 100 steps = 600 ms.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a init function and clear your pie. So you can call that after `clearInterval(progInc)`.

```
  function initPie() {
        quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
            quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
            quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0deg)');
            quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skewY(0deg)');
      progress = progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', '-1');
      progInc = setInterval(incrementProg, 100);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5e9hs69y/11/

Answer (score 0):

To start over you need to make `progress` 0 once it reaches 100, and do not clearInterval. Then you will need to revert the style into initial state.

Example (worked for me https://jsfiddle.net/mvv07jdk/ ):

```
if (progress == 100) {
    progressbar.setAttribute('data-progress', 0);
    quad1.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0)');
    quad2.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0)');
    quad3.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0)'); 
    quad4.setAttribute('style', 'transform: skew(0)');
}
```